# Failed to load resource 404 error when I deploy to vercel

Tags: deployment, http-status-code-404, vercel

I have built a simple ChatGPT API site that works locally, but once I deployed it to Vercel, the API calls don't seem to be working.

I have a server.mjs running the API and my frontend code is handling the response

When I run it the error is:

> script.js:50     GET https://daily-tarot.vercel.app/tarot?card=Knight%20of%20Wands 404

(line 50 is below: it's the `console.error` line)

Vercel is also flagging an issue with my route /tarot, but that is working locally.

The issue seems to be about the server not being correctly configured to handle the routes when deployed to Vercel, but I am not sure what is wrong.

This is the code within the front-end API code that seems to be causing the problem.

Again, this same code works when the URL is set to localhost

```js
 let url = `https://daily-tarot.vercel.app/tarot?card=${card}`;


  displayLoading();
  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);
    console.log(response)
    const result = await response.json();
    const resultText = result.response;
    displayMeaning(resultText);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

This is the server side code

```js
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import express from 'express';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import cors from 'cors';

dotenv.config();

const app = express();

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use(cors());

const API_KEY = process.env.API_KEY;


app.get('/tarot', async (req, res)=>{
    const {card} = req.query; 
    console.log("Received card: ", card);
    const url = "https://chatgpt-ai-chat-bot.p.rapidapi.com/ask";
    const options = {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": API_KEY,
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "chatgpt-ai-chat-bot.p.rapidapi.com",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            query: 
            //the question for ChatGPT with the ${card}. passed in.
        }),

    };
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log("API Response: ", result);
        res.json(result);
    }catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: error.message });
    }
}
);
```

I have been working on this bug all day.

I have repeatedly ran it through devtool debugger to figure out which lines of code are causing the issue.

Checked for deployment errors, and ran checks through vercel.

I also manually checked the API on Postman, the API itself works but when the deployed link instead of localhost is added it gets the 404.